# How to limit framerate in Unity without causing screentears?

Tags: unity

Is there any way to limit framerate in Unity without causing screentears in build? I cannot seem to do it, but Valheim has an fps-slider and they use Unity, so thinking there must be a way?

I am aware of v-sync, but I'm talking about using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use v-sync for this purpose?

Comment: You would use `Application.targetFramerate` to limit the framerate, and v-sync to prevent tearing. That's literally what v-sync is for.

Comment: @DMGregory because some players have screens with 250+ refreshrate, and my game has no reason at all to play over 60FPS, it will just cause GPUs to run hotter than they have to.

Comment: @Kevin you cant use both, if you enable v-sync, targetframerate is ignored.

Comment: So why not use v-sync to reduce the high refresh rate to something closer to 60? (eg. using "every fourth v-blank" with a 240 Hz monitor to divide it back down to 60 fps).

Comment: @Majs Whoops! You're correct; I'm used to working on mobile where vsync is always on and `Application.targetFramerate` is used to limit the maximum framerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the way you enable vSync in Unity is by setting the value [`QualitySettings.vSyncCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-vSyncCount.html), which is an integer value, with 4 being the allowed maximum. The target framerate becomes the monitor refresh rate divided by that integer. Which can be obtained via [`RefreshRate.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RefreshRate-value.html). So if you want both vSync and a limited framerate that is lower than the refresh rate, then you can just set the vSyncCount to the correct factor.

The documentation says that the maximum allowed vSyncCount is 4, but the behavior you get when you set it to a higher value is undocumented. So I would recommend to [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) the value to the range of 1 to 4.

So if you want to have a limit of (as close as possible to) 60 Fps while also having vSync enabled, then you can do this:

```
float vSyncFactor = RefreshRate.value / 60.0f;
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.RoundToInteger(vSyncFactor), 1, 4);
```

Due to vSyncCount being an integer, you can not rely on getting *exactly* 60 FPS. For example, a 144Hz monitor will result in a framerate of 72 FPS. So while you do reach your goal to keep the players GPU reasonably cool, you will still need to have those `* Time.deltaTime` multiplication in your Update-methods.

Comment: Thats an interesting approach, I had something similar in mind as a plan B if targetframerate simply always causes screentears. Atm I offer v-sync or half-vsync.

Comment: From reading around more I think this is as close as I'll get to what I want, thanks!