I want to limit my in-game FPS in my Unity game to 20 FPS, but this causes screen tearing in the build. How do I get rid of the tearing?
I have tried vSync, but in other forums I have read the vSync ignores the targetFramerate. Is there a way I can keep a 20 FPS cap without screen tearing? In my game I am trying to achieve a nostalgic feel of the PSX, but the PSX certainly didn't render the game at 600 FPS burning my computer up for a simple game. I use a separate script attached to an empty game object to limit the FPS with a script attached as a component. This is my first time using Stack Exchange, because I usually find my answers on already existing posts.
Here is the code I have in that C# script:
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPS_Limiter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int targetFPS = 20;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        Application.targetFrameRate = targetFPS;
    }
}


@CheckerT that seems to be in the code the asker posted above, no? (With the correct capitalization, too)

On all other platforms, Unity ignores the value of targetFrameRate if you set vSyncCount. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-vSyncCount.html And setting once in Start should be enough as well

Duplicate of https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205365/how-to-limit-framerate-in-unity-without-causing-screentears ?

On a desktop platform (Windows, Mac, or Linux), you can set the V-Sync count to be the refresh rate of the monitor divided by your target framerate.
e.g. if the monitor refresh rate is 60 Hz, 60/20 = 3, meaning we render once every three screen refreshes. If the monitor refresh rate is 120, 120/20 = 6, meaning we render once every six screen refreshes.
Linking the rendering to the vertical sync ensures we only ever present full frames to the screen - we never swap in the midst of a draw, which is what causes tearing.
On mobile platforms, vSyncCount is ignored, so using targetFramerate is your best bet there.
Here's your code modified to take this into account:
public class FPS_Limiter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int targetFPS = 20;

    void Start()
    {
#if (UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_LINUX)
        var refreshRate = (float)Screen.currentResolution.refreshRateRatio.value;
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(refreshRate / targetFPS);
#else
        Application.targetFrameRate = targetFPS;
#endif
    }
}


Note that the only supported values of QualitySettings.vSyncCount are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, so this probably won't work for any monitor with a refresh rate faster than about 80Hz.

Good catch! I wonder why they have that limit. With some monitors going up to 360 Hz these days, it would make sense to revise that behaviour.

I assume the limit is inherited from IDXGISwapChain::Present.
